# What is hiding behind amortized constant delay enumeration?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, strings, amortized-analysis, enumeration

*The following may contain errors. It is precisely because I am not
sure I understand the topic that I am asking questions. I do not have
books about it and could not find an adequate reference on the web.*

I am discussing a problem regarding an enumeration of strings that
should be in **amortized constant delay**. From what I understood (but
understanding that is part of my question), this means that the average
time taken for each answer should be independent of the size of the
answer, so that the total cost is $O(n)$ where $n$ is the number of
answers.

My discussion partner went on to assert (I believe) that amortized
constant delay is possible for enumerating the strings accepted by a
trie, but not for enumerating the paths of a DAG. And I am at loss to
see a significant difference, since proper use of a stack should let
me explore the DAG as if it had been exploded into a trie (by
duplicating whatever is below a merge vertex).

The only real difference I can see is that the accepting nodes of a
trie can be labeled with a single symbol identifier characterizing the accepted word (turning the trie
into a Moore machine) so that the total cost is only a traversal of
the trie, with single step output of the symbol label when traversing an
accepting node.

Such labeling identification is not possible for a DFA structured as a DAG, since an
accepting node can correspond to different paths. The only way to name
paths is to describe them in extenso (or nearly so: enough to disambiguate merges), so that the cost
of the output by itself is already something like $O(n\times s)$ where
$s$ is the size of the longest path, thus entailing the same time cost
just for doing the output.

Where do I err, and what is the accepted wisdom and knowledge on this topic?
Pointers to web references are useful too.

Comment: Taking 'answer' to mean the output of a single element of the enumeration, I believe that amortized constant delay does not address the average time taken for one such answer but the average time between 2 consecutive outputs. in a trie that would be constant for one would have to backtrack to the most recent node with some successor edge not yet visited. thus in total there would be one $O(n)$ DFS required for the output of at max $n$ strings in a trie of $n$ nodes.

Comment: @collapsar Thanks. The point of the discussion I mention is that complexity was
not with respect to the size of the trie or whatever other structure
is used, but with respect to the number and size of the answers, as
well as some other initial parameters. And in such a case, I do not
see that there is any difference between the trie and an acyclic DFA
that does the same job (other than the naming trick I suggest in the
question). My discussion partner is asserting that "It's not known how
to enumerate source,sink-paths in a dag with constant delay". Does
this refer to something real?

Comment: The way I understand the problem, constant amortized delay mandates that all structures needed for bookkeeping of the enumeration elements processed need to be maintained in (average) constant time. for tries that's granted. however, i don't see an obvious solution in the dag case. i have a reference presenting [an optimal st-path enumeration algorithm](http://knowledgecenter.siam.org/0236-000084/~~PdfSource/0) showcasing the issue ...

Comment: ...  [Lemma 4.3, p.1891](http://knowledgecenter.siam.org/0236-000084/8) referring to [Algorithm 1, p.1888](http://knowledgecenter.siam.org/0236-000084/5) shows the total cost of their recursion tree for the maintenance of a bookkeeping data structure is the sum of the lengths of all st-paths. caveat: i'm not well-versed in interpreting research-level papers so i may have missed/misunderstood some aspects.

Comment: @collapsar Seems paper never considers directed graphs. Assume (no
generality loss) the graph has a unique start node (root). You push it
on a stack. For each node on the stack, if accepting print the path
found in the stack. Then if outgoing edges, choose 1, say e, and
memorize the others with the node on stack. Then push e and the
node at the other end. After processing a leaf (no outgoing edge), pop
top node and edge, and go down the next edge of the node on top of
stack as before. If no next edge, pop again. This walks all paths
from root to accepting nodes, and has the path in the stack.

Comment: thanks for your patient explanation. while the stack based dfs covers all paths, arbitrarily many branches may be dead ends. there is no guarantee about the time spent with the dfs between consecutive encounters of an accepting node. the hard cases for the delay time will thus be dags with $O(f(n))$ paths starting at the start node with $o(f(n))$ of them ending at the target node (this argument would not apply to s-t-digraphs) ...

Comment: ... sample instance: lattice graph $D_n = (\{v_{ij}: (i,j)\in\mathbb N^2, 0\leq i+j\leq n\}\cup\{t\}, \{(v_{ij},v_{(i+1)j}): v_{ij}\in D_{n-1}\}\cup\{(v_{ij},v_{i(j+1)}): v_{ij}\in D_{n-1}\}\cup\{(v_{0n},t)\}\cup\{(v_{n0},t)\})$. there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$ nodes, $2^n+2$ maximal paths starting at $v_{00}$ but only 2 paths from $v_{00}$ to $t$).

Comment: Sorry, I skipped details. The useless nodes and arcs can be removed in
linear time. Same as removing unproductive states and transitions in a
NFA. Actually, the DAG I am interested in is a DFA. I will give you a pointer when the issue is settled. Thanks for your help.